# Simple layout - java swing

Tags: java, swing, layout

I want to make a simple layout, something like this:

[image]

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AIvt.png/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AIvt.png)

I can do this without Layout manager but I need use it. I tried to do it myself however I failed.

Comment: All you need to know:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: *"I tried to do it myself however I failed"* - Ok, [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [`LayoutManager`'s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Try next:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public TestFrame() {
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=0;

        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1;
        add(getLbl(),c);


        JPanel left = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3,5,5));
        for(int i =0;i<9;i++){
            left.add(getLbl());
        }

        JPanel right = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2,5,5));
        for(int i =0;i<6;i++){
            right.add(getLbl());
        }

        c.weightx = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridy++;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        add(left,c);

        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        c.gridx++;
        add(right,c);
    }


    private JLabel getLbl() {
        JLabel l = new JLabel("   ");
        l.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        return l;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot to write that may be a simple GUI for calculator - on the top JTextField, below JButton. Actually I'm trying learn & test Grid and Flow Layouts.

Comment: Now you know how to layout components,  change label's to textfield/button

Answer (score 0):

the layout you have mentioned in the image like a Grid or Table
So you can either use the GridLayout
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#grid

or TableLayout

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/tablelayout-141489.html

I hope this could help!